# Упрощение записи длинного switch-case

Tags: c++, c

В программе есть функция, которая в зависимости от выбранного адреса выполняет запись переданного значения в некоторые переменные. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
int reg_write(uint16_t addr, uint16_t value)
{
  switch(addr)
  {
  case S0_1_A:
    return write_to(value, 0, 1, SA);
  case S0_2_B:
    return write_to(value, 0, 2, SB);
    .
    .
    .
  case S1_12_B:
    return write_to(value, 1, 12, SB);
  default:
    return ERROR_CODE;
  }
}
```

То есть есть диапазон адресов и в зависимости от адреса я делаю запись в некоторую переменную одной из 2-х структур s0 или s1. То есть, например:

```
int write(uint16_t value, int sn, int n, enum SE se)
{
   if(se == SA)
      s[sn].a[n] = value;
   else
      s[sn].b[n] = value;
}
```

Пример условный, на самом деле у меня намного больше и структур и переменных. Константы Sxxx имеют вообще говоря произвольные значения, но для одной структуры S они идут строго по порядку, но есть "дыры"(S0_1_A, S0_1_B, S0_2_A, S0_5_A, S0_5B), за индексом 2 идет сразу 5.
 Нужно иметь код не привязанный к значениям адреса.
Вопрос: как можно максимально упростить запись подобного switch-case?
Компилятор GCC, пользоваться можно любыми средствами. Может даже какой-то кодогенерацией, но желательно как можно проще и по возможности на C, не на C++.

Comment: Сделать таблицу типа значение/функция, и поиск в ней. Только будет медленнее работать...

Comment: `std::map<uint16_t, std::pair<uint8_t, uint8_t> = {{S0_1, {0 ,1}}, ...}`

Comment: А чему равны константы `SX_X`? Нельзя ли значения  `sn` и `n` вытащить наложением битовой маски?

Comment: Нельзя привязаться к значению адреса. Но известно, что для одного S(например, для S0) адреса идут по порядку (S0_1_A, S0_1_B, S0_2_A...итд)

Comment: Что-то у Вас вопрос меняется как хамелеон на куче скиттлс,  подгонять каждый раз ответ под новые условия совсем не интересно.

Comment: Да, согласен. Прошу прощения. Просто у меня реальный пример намного сложнее этого, и я хотел придумать что-то простое и одновременно учитывающее все детали моего примера. Но сейчас пример окончательный.

Comment: @Reffum А где эти константы объявлены ? есть ведь какой нибудь .h файл в котором они все перечислены ... можно сделать скрипт на любом боле менее знакомом языке обработки текстов который считает этот файл констант и на основе них сгенерит таблицу переходов (генерить гигантский switch конечно не стоит).

Comment: @Mike Спасибо. Так и сделал. Скопировал объявления этих констант в свой файл и сделал замену по регулярному выражению. Получился гигантский switch-case. Но это, видимо, единственный вариант.

Comment: @Reffum Ну switch-case все таки не оч хорошо, надо смотреть как он оптимизируется, я бы все таки, как вам в ответе предлагали, таблицу бы завел. А перед этим глазами посмотрел на те числа, которые скрываются за этими именами, может в них есть какая то математическая или битовая закономерность, по которой можно было бы вычислить параметры прямо из числа. Если хотите выложите куда нибудь файл с объявлениями, интересно глянуть, может увижу что нибудь ...

Comment: @Mike Выложить, не могу. Я не могу привязываться к значениям констант, так как они могу поменяться. А какой таблице Вы говорите?

Comment: @Reffum О той, о которой написано в ответе, который вы отметили как принятый

Comment: @Mike Такую таблицу заполнять еще сложнее, чем сделать switch-case.

Comment: @Reffum Ну да, конечно генератор который ее создаст одной регуляркой не напишеш, строки 3 на perl придется делать небось ну или десяток строк на каком нибудь php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша задача в общем случае сводится к необходимости получения отображения одной целочисленной величины (адрес) на набор других (возможно разнотипных):

```
addr -> { sn, n, se }
```

Вариантов решения может быть несколько:

1. Т.к. `addr` задается 16битным значением, их не так много (65536) и можно сформировать таблицу (массив), где индексом будет выступать адрес, а значение по этому индексу будет хранить структуру с подходящим набором значений.
2. Использовать не массив, а `std::map`/`std::unordered_map` (для C++), если веток немного (много меньше 64К), то это может быть выгоднее.
3. Если существует (может быть её просто надо понять) известная логика формирования целевых значений от адреса, то эту логику можно реализовать в виде функции. А дальше использовать результат этой функции в качестве нужного набора.
4. Совместить способ 3 с (1 или 2) для заполнения массива/отображения в процессе выполнения программы при инициализации, и в последующих вызовах использовать уже готовую таблицу.

Максимальной лаконичности кода можно будет добиться только если найти зависимость выхода от входа. Если такой зависимости нет - придется так или иначе заполнять таблицу вручную. Но использование таблицы всё равно предпочтительнее, чем `switch` на несколько экранов.

Comment: "Лаконичность кода". Так получается громадный switch-case, я просто думаю как его ввести. Таблица не решит проблемы, ее тоже нужно как-то вводить.

Comment: @Reffum если есть какая-то известная логика формирования `sn`, `n` от `addr`, то просто нужно создать такую функцию/пару функций, и вызывать `write_to(value, f(sn, n), g(sn, n));` вместо громадного `switch`.